# How to check current call or current call state in Linphone

Tags: ios, swift, linphone, callkit

I want to check incoming call is received or not by using Linphone for showing CallKit view. But when we get a current call in Linphone is does not return. Can I check the current call state is Incoming or not? When call state is Incoming I show the CallKit view otherwise not. I am using below code for getting the current call.

```
func getCurrentCall() -> Optional<OpaquePointer>
    {
        if let call = linphone_core_get_current_call(theLinphone.lc)
        {
            return call
        }
        else
        {
            return nil
        }
    }
```